What does it mean to multiply rectangular matrices?
I understand matrix multiplication as linear transformation of one or more vectors based on the transformation matrix. This can be visualized when both the matrices are square and are of same dimensions. But what if we multiply a matrix $A$ of order $2 \times 3$  with a matrix $B$ of order $3 \times 1$? The product is a $2 \times 1$ matrix. The vector $B$ which is 3-dimensional is being transformed to a 2-dimensional by three two-dimensional column vectors of $A$. How can a three-dimensional vector be transformed into a two-dimensional?

It's the same principal of the shade of a person :-)

can you elaborate?

One simple linear  transformation from a two dimensional space to a three dimensional space is $(x,y,z) \to (x,y)$.

Note that a three dimensional space like $\Bbb{R}^3$ cannot be mapped onto $\Bbb{R}^2$ in a way that is both linear and invertible. Some kind of squashing has to occur; the map will have to have a non-trivial kernel, which will be squashed into the zero vector.

As another user said in a comment, the "squishing" of a three-dimensional figure onto a two-dimensional plane can be thought of as a shadow. When you stand in sunlight your shadow is a two-dimensional representation of your three-dimensional self. A similar process is happening when we transform a vector in $\Bbb R^3$ to $\Bbb R^2$.
In a more concrete sense, each column of the transformation matrix represents a projection from 3-space to a plane. When we combine these together and multiply them with weights, we can obtain a two-dimensional representation of our original vector in $\Bbb R^3$
One application of these kinds of transformations is computer graphics where three-dimensional scenes are projected onto a two-dimensional plane, your screen!

TQSM for the concise explanation
